# What's a damning book?

Tags: word-meaning

https://edition.cnn.com/2018/09/05/politics/nyt-trump-resistance-op-ed/index.html

> The op-ed offers a first-hand account that corroborates key themes of
>   a new **damning book** about Trump’s presidency by the veteran journalist
>   Bob Woodward: that some of the President’s top advisers have a dim
>   view of the commander in chief and are quietly working to thwart
>   Trump’s most reckless and impulsive decisions from becoming a reality.

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/damning) : "A damning report, judgment, remark, etc. that includes a lot of criticism or shows clearly that someone is wrong, guilty, or has behaved very badly"

Comment: @Jay A. Little  Great answer. You should write that up as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @James Honestly, I thought this Q would be flagged as: *"Basic questions on spelling, meaning or pronunciation are off-topic as they should be answered using a dictionary."* Since the question is answered with a single dictionary definition. So I just wanted to point the OP to the correct definition in a comment before that happened.

Comment: @JayA.Little, different dictionaries have different meanings, My dictionary doesn't have this meaning.

Comment: I totally understand. That's exactly why I always have at least 3 dictionaries when I study, and check even more than that if I can access the internet to find the best fitting definitions of words. Cambridge just happened to give the perfect definition for this use of "damning". Sometimes its Merriam-Webster or Oxford or even Urban Dictionary! It depends on the use and context and many other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Damning book* is not an idiom or compound word and can be taken literally according to the dictionary definition of the words.